# Fetch set of images joining tables inside a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just register to Stack Overflow, I looked for a post like this one but what I found was a group of different posts but I'm not smart enough(yet!) to put them together to answer my question.

I like to learn programming with, let's say "real" examples after I finish my online courses or books.

---

[What I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUfpT.jpg)

As you can see in my link is what I want to achieve. Initially I had all the data in one table but I've been reading on this site that is not the best practice to store the images paths separated by commas in just one field. So right now I have:

- 1 table with all the info.
- 1 table (so far) with a collection of pictures for my first ad.

So, my question is, I don't know how exactly do I have to join the tables and use the while loop to be able to fetch as many pictures as I need per ad, to later on, use those pictures in a Lightbox gallery...

so far I was only able to put 1 picture per ad! :S

my 1st table is structured like this

| ID | HOUSE-TYPE | CITY | TITLE | DESCRIPTION | PICS | SQRMETER | PRICE | TELPHONE | EMAIL

my 2nd table is structured like this:

| ID | PATH | TITLE | ALT |

And my code so far:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM t_test");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<div class='ad'>" .
             "<h2>" .  "OFFER " . $row[offer] . $row[house-type] . " in " . $row[city] . 
             "</h2>" .
             "<h1>" . $row[title] . "</h1>" .
             "<p>" . $row[description] . "</p>" . 
             "<img src='" . $row[photo] . "'/>" .
             "<p class='pics-per-ad'>" . "TOTAL PICS" . "</p>" .
             "<p class='square-meters'>" . $row[sqmeter] . " metros 2" . "</p>" .
             "<p class='price'>" . $row[price] . " Euros" . "</p>" . 
             "<p class='telephone'>" . $row[telphone] . "</p>" . 
             "<p class='email'>" . $row[email] . "</p>" .                                
        "</div>"; 

  }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: what columns are you trying to join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions for what you are trying to achieve. I would suggest to keep this simple is to have another column in your pics table called linked, this would link your image to your ad.

Try and follow these steps below.

1. Create a column in your pic table called 'linked'

   ```
   ALTER TABLE ads ADD linked VARCHAR(255)
   ```
2. create a foreign key relationship between your pics table and your ad's table. 
   (if your ad gets deleted or updated for example, it will also delete your image from the pics table)
3. In your code join your tables by doing something like this.

   ```
   $query = '
   SELECT ads.*, pics.*  FROM ads
   LEFT JOIN pics ON pics.linked = ads.id
   ';

   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
   ```

Comment: Hello! about step #2:

Do I have to create the relationship using the columns "linked" from my pictures table with the column "ID" in my ad table?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Setting a foreign key is not mandatory though.

Answer (score 0):

Each ad can have multiple pics, so you need to setup a "one-to-many" relationship in your database. You do this by using foreign keys.

- In the ads table, each ad has a unique ID already
- In the pics table, in addition to each one having *it's* own unique ID, there should be an additional field for the ads_ID which it belongs to.
- When you go to display ad ID x, then you query the db to get all pics with ads_ID x:

"SELECT * FROM pics WHERE ads_ID = x"